# Tensorflow 'Accuracy' object has no attribute '_serialized_attributes' error while using load_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('inception-KLDivergence')
```

The above code produces the error :

```
AttributeError: 'Accuracy' object has no attribute '_serialized_attributes'
```

Model was saved using `model.save()` in `SavedModel` format.

Comment: Can you share complete code or model.h5 file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change all your `from keras` to `from tensorflow.keras` so that `load_model()` and `save()` are coming from `tensorflow.keras` and not `keras`

Ensure you do this both when you save the model and when you load it

See https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13590#issuecomment-643889497

This fixed it for me